# Adding a Row into an alphabetically ordered SQL table

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL table with two columns:

- 'id' `int` `Auto_Increment`
- instancename `varchar`

The current 114 rows are ordered alphabetically after instancename.

Now i want to insert a new row that fits into the order.

So say it starts with a 'B', it would be at around id 14 and therefore had to 'push down' all of the rows after id 14. How do i do this?

Comment: I think you didn't get the point of ordering SQL tables. You order them when querying, don't care how they are actually ordered when inserting, deleting, or updating.

Comment: Is there a reason you need them ordered this way? Why not use `Order By instancename` iny our select statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  IDs shouldn't be changed.  If you have tables that reference these IDs as foreign keys then the DBMS wouldn't let you change them, anyway.

Instead, if you need results from a *specific query* to be ordered alphabetically, tell SQL to order it for you:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY instancename
```

As an aside, sometimes you want something that can seemingly be a key (read- needs to be unique for each row) but does have to change from time to time (such as something like a SKU in a product table).  This should not be the primary key for the same reason (there are undoubtedly other tables that may refer to these entries, each of which would also need to be updated).

Keeping this information distinct will help keep you and everyone else working on the project from going insane.

Answer (score 5):

An SQL table is not inherently ordered!  (It is just a set.)  You would simply add the new row and view it using something like:

```
  select instancename
    from thetable
   order by instancename;
```

Comment: User means that id's are ordered alphabetically

Comment: The questioner may have meant that for his initial set of data, ordering by instancename also showed that the ids were in order. However, this is NOT a relationship that should be relied upon ... it is a happenstance of history, not a design.

Answer (score -1):

Try using an over and joining to self.

```
Update  thetable
Set     ID = r.ID
From    thetable c Join
        ( Select instancename, Row_Number() Over(Order By instancename) As ID 
              From CollectionStatus) r On c.instancename= r.instancename
```

This should update the id column to the ordered number.  You may have to disable it's identity first.